# Python Tk Menu Delete command , Menu.reDraw()?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I have a TK Menu widget, and would like to remove the command when clicked on, after doing some side effect stuff. All the code is in a `DocumentView` class, hence the `self.varnames`

```
self.root= Tk()
self.root.title("Document Screen")
self.root.geometry(str(DocHeight)+"x"+str(DocHeight))

self.mainMenu = Menu(self.root)
self.allMembersMenu = Menu(self.updateMembersMenu)
for member in self.allUsers:
    self.allMembersMenu.add_command(label=member,command=lambda i= member: 
self.removeUser(i))
```

This makes a command for every user in the system. Remove user is defined as follows

```
def removeUser(self,uname):

    print("Remove User Function , uname: {}".format(uname))
    x=0

    mem = self.currentDoc.getMembers()
    delmem=""
    for i in range(0,len(mem)):
        if (mem[i]==uname):
            x=i
            delmem = mem[i]
            break


    self.allMembersMenu.delete(x)
    self.allUserMenu.destroy
    self.currentDoc.removeMember(delmem)
```

Using the print function I know the correct variables are being passed, but no change is occurring in the Menu, is there some sort of `Menu.reDraw()` method I'm missing?

If that doesn't exist is there a way to destroy this submenu and redraw it?

Comment: `self.allMembersMenu.delete(x)` works when I run the code with some minor changes, so I'm afraid the problem is somewhere in the code that you're not showing. You should try to create a [mcve], that we can copy-paste and run and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x600")
root.option_add("*tearOff", False)

menuBar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menuBar)

usersMenu = tk.Menu(menuBar)

delUserMenu = tk.Menu(menuBar)
menuBar.add_cascade(menu=usersMenu, label="Users")
usersMenu.add_cascade(menu=delUserMenu,  label="Delete")


usernamelist = ["Ali", "Ahmed", "Muhamed"]

def del_user(username):
    delUserMenu.delete(delUserMenu.index(username))
    print(username, "deleted!")

def command(username): return lambda :del_user(username)

for username in usernamelist:
    delUserMenu.add_command(label=username, command=command(username))

root.mainloop()
```